# SEO - Delete old indexed pages from Google 301 vs 404?

Tags: seo, google-index

We're launching new website with new url structure and new content. Domain is the same.
Many old pages are indexed by google. Should I use 404 or 301 and redirect to '/' for these old resources? I also want to remove these pages from google index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use HTTP 410 (Gone) for pages you'd like to stop from being indexed.

For changed URLs with the same content use HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently).

Comment: It's impossible to redirect exactly to new url, all redirects need to point main site. 410 returns default browser error page I would like to redirect user to new location (based on 'location' header)

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:google-index], I assumed it was *about* Google indexing your page... There's no "default browser error page" on Google. Maybe you'll need to base your HTTP response codes on the User-Agents?

Comment: giving different HTTP response codes to different User-Agents is a bad idea and opens you to Google thinking you look spammy.

Answer (score 3):

If the content has moved permanently, then a 301 response is the correct thing to do (and point it to the new location, **not** a generic point); If the content has gone forever, you should use the 410 response which means "Gone". Of course, where there is an alternate, you can use a 303 response (along with the URL to the alternate) which can be worthwhile when there isn't an exact match.